# The area of the hysteresis curve from the photo from the oscilloscope. (opencv)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: Original]

[image: Result]

Good evening, I have some problems correcting an image after removing grid to get area of that curve. I have tried `erode` and `dilate` after and before removing grid, but i have had a bad curve after that. Maybe you can advise me a more efficient way to correct the curve.

```py
import sys

import cv2
import numpy as np


def remove_grid_lines(src):
    clean_lines_h = remove_lines(src, np.ones((1, 10), np.uint8), np.ones((1, 5), np.uint8))
    clean_lines_v = remove_lines(src, np.ones((10, 1), np.uint8), np.ones((5, 1), np.uint8))
    return cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.bitwise_not(src) - clean_lines_h - clean_lines_v)


def remove_lines(src, kernel1, kernel2):
    erosion = cv2.erode(src, kernel1, iterations=1)
    dilation = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel1, iterations=1))
    clean_lines = cv2.dilate(cv2.erode(dilation, kernel2, iterations=6), kernel2, iterations=6)
    return clean_lines


def main(argv):
    original_image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(argv[0]), (640, 640))
    grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    grayscale_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale_image, (3, 3), 0)

    (thresh, binary_image) = cv2.threshold(grayscale_image, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    binary_image = cv2.bitwise_not(binary_image)
    cv2.imshow("Original", original_image)
    cv2.imshow("Grayscale", grayscale_image)
    cv2.imshow("Binary", binary_image)

    binary_image = remove_grid_lines(binary_image)

    cv2.imshow("Clean", binary_image)

    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: is there any way you can shut off the graticules in the scope itself?

Comment: @Christoph , As far as I know there is no such feature in this model.

Comment: invert the picture, so the terms make sense. foreground is always white/1/true, background is black/0/false. now call connectedComponentsWithStats and erase all the pieces that are tiny (small bounding boxes). then, apply a morphological closing operation. see if that manages to connect the lines.